# constructor parent in parent class cannot be applied to given types error

Tags: java, inheritance, builder, lombok

I want to extend a parent class say:

```
@Getter
@Builder
public class Parent {

@Builder.default
private final int maxCats = 1;

@NonNull
private final String catName;
}
```

I am proceeding as follows,

```
@Getter
@ToString
@Builder
public class child extends Parent{

@Builder.default
private final int maxCats = 100;

@NonNull
private final String catName;

@Builder.Default
private final int maxDogs = 500;
}
```

When I am building the package I am getting following error:

```
error: constructor Parent in class Parent cannot be applied to given types;
[javac] @Builder
[javac] ^
[javac]   required: int,String
[javac]   found: no arguments
[javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Can anyone help me figure out reason for error?

P.S: Parent class should not be modified.

Answer (score 2):

`@Builder` does not work well with inheritance. It uses a generated constructor which always calls the default constructor of the superclass. That does not exist in your case.

If you are OK with using experimental features, try `@SuperBuilder`. However, you need that annotation on both classes, so there is no way to avoid modifying `Parent`. Furthermore, `@SuperBuilder` is not yet supported in IntelliJ.

Alternatively you could you write a manual constructor with all fields as parameters (also those from the superclass) and put `@Builder` on that. (Note: Avoid `@Builder.Default` in this case, as it removes the field initializers.)